# Four model training simultaneously in a single machine with 8 gpus

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, multiprocessing, jupyter, multi-gpu

I have a 8-gpu workstation for deep learning using tensorflow.
The work station specifications are as follows:
Intel Xeon Gold x2
NVIDIA Quadro RTXA6000 x8
RAM 1TB

I use:
Python 3.8
UBUNTU 20.04
Tensorflow 2.8
CUDA 11.2
cuDNN 8.1

I hope to run four jupyter notebooks simultaneously to train four models. I think using 8 gpus for a single model training is not very efficient. However, the notebook died during training and I got several warning messages.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix these errors and are these related to running multiple notebooks?

```
[E 13:32:28.388 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
        f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
        return callback(self, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 572, in _on_zmq_reply
        super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 256, in _on_zmq_reply
        self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 339, in write_message
        return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1086, in write_message
        fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1061, in _write_frame
        return self.stream.write(frame)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 546, in write
        self._handle_write()
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 976, in _handle_write
        self._write_buffer.advance(num_bytes)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 182, in advance
        assert 0 < size <= self._size
    AssertionError

[E 13:32:28.388 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 621, in _handle_events
        self._handle_recv()
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 650, in _handle_recv
        self._run_callback(callback, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
        f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
        return callback(self, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 572, in _on_zmq_reply
        super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 256, in _on_zmq_reply
        self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 339, in write_message
        return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1086, in write_message
        fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1061, in _write_frame
        return self.stream.write(frame)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 546, in write
        self._handle_write()
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 976, in _handle_write
        self._write_buffer.advance(num_bytes)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 182, in advance
        assert 0 < size <= self._size
    AssertionError
    
[E 13:32:28.389 NotebookApp] Exception in callback functools.partial(<function ZMQStream._update_handler.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f5da3064310>)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 740, in _run_callback
        ret = callback()
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 705, in <lambda>
        self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda: self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 621, in _handle_events
        self._handle_recv()
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 650, in _handle_recv
        self._run_callback(callback, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
        f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
        return callback(self, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 572, in _on_zmq_reply
        super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 256, in _on_zmq_reply
        self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 339, in write_message
        return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1086, in write_message
        fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1061, in _write_frame
        return self.stream.write(frame)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 546, in write
        self._handle_write()
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 976, in _handle_write
        self._write_buffer.advance(num_bytes)
      File "/home/super/researchvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 182, in advance
        assert 0 < size <= self._size
    AssertionError
```

Running multiple jupyter notebooks in a single machine for multiple simultaneous TF model training

Comment: I would not do those training sessions in parallel.  Run one, let it finish, run the next.

Comment: Thank you. But would training multiple models at the same time in parallel save time and enable efficient hyperparameter searching?

Comment: The error message itself is not mentioning anything about TF, therefore looks more like notebook question to me. Try launching your trainings with a plain python script.

Comment: "saves time" - not if they don't all run.  Sounds like you need to run these on multiple machines.

Comment: Yes, the messages are not related with TF. Probably running multiple notebooks at the same time causes some errors related to tornado, threading, or multiprocessing... That's what I assume based on the web searching thus far.